# SQL Server 2014: one column to multiple columns with less rows, how to pivot a table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, pivot-table, multiple-columns

I want to break a column into many columns and combine some columns. How can I do the modification in SQL Server 2012?

**Input**

```
|   Cust   |    Q     |    Val     |
------------------------------------
|    1     |    1     |    10      |
|    2     |    2     |    20      |
|    1     |    2     |    30      |
|    4     |    4     |    40      |
|    4     |    1     |    400     |
|    4     |    2     |    4000    |
```

**Output: how to get here from the input?**

```
|   Cust   |   ValQI  |   ValQII   |   ValQIII   |    VALQIV    |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
|    1     |    10    |    30      |             |              |
|    2     |          |    20      |             |              |
|    3     |          |            |             |              |
|    4     |    400   |    4000    |             |      40      |
```

Comment: How many different values in Q?

Comment: @etsa each year has 4 quarters so 10 years have 40 quarters and so on.

Comment: How you get output with cust 3? I think you have one record missed in input with cust 3?

Comment: @KannanKandasamy Good point, noticed some mistyping, fixed them, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Combined PIVOT an LEFT OUTER JOIN

```
WITH C AS
(
    SELECT *
    FROM (VALUES (1), (2), (3), (4)) AS T(Cust)
)
SELECT C.Cust, [1] AS ValQI, [2] AS ValQII, [3] AS ValQIII, [4] AS ValQIV
FROM C
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
(
    SELEcT *
    FROM 
    (VALUES 
        (1, 1, 10), 
        (2, 2, 20), 
        (1, 2, 30), 
        (4, 4, 40), 
        (4, 1, 400), 
        (4, 2, 4000)
    ) AS T(Cust, Q, Val)
    PIVOT (MAX([Val]) FOR [Q] IN ([1], [2], [3], [4])) AS P
) AS TT ON C.Cust = TT.Cust
```

Comment: Can you explain what the `max` is for? The case is not taking any maximum value of the values so I am doubting why it is there.

Comment: PIVOT performs GROUP BY internally. How would pick up a value inside a group? In your case, as there is no duplication, it can be MIN/MAX/SUM/AVERAGE.

Comment: I think 90 is for 2005 and 2012 is 110. Could you double check compatibility level by `SELECT name, compatibility_level FROM sys.databases;` and check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-database-transact-sql-compatibility-level?

Comment: The compatibility level is 120, apparently SQL Server 2014 and  engine 12 by that document (apparently not SQL Server 2012?).

Comment: I can't repro the error with with compatibility level 110 or 120. Can you tell which 'Cust' is causing error?

Comment: I fixed that: I had to change the last select like this [here](https://pastebin.com/wQRGUZ8X), I changed the selection thing to the form like `SELECT [NET_VALUE_Q] as [Val] ... FROM DATA` instead of `SELECT * FROM DATA as T([Val]...)`. What could cause the invalid col things? I am trying to replace the demo data with other select command.

Answer (score 0):

You can use pivot in SQL Server to transpose data like this in SQL Server..

```
;with cte as (
select cust, RowN = Row_Number() over (partition by cust order by q), val from #yourPivot )
select * from cte
pivot (max(val) for RowN in ([1],[2], [3],[4])) p
```

Your input table:

```
create table #yourPivot (cust int, Q int, Val int)

insert into #yourPivot (cust, q, val) values
 (   1    ,   1     ,    10      )
,(   2    ,   2     ,    20      )
,(   1    ,   1     ,    30      )
,(   4    ,   4     ,    40      )
,(   4    ,   1     ,    400     )
,(   4    ,   2     ,    4000    )
```